# imacros cut a part of txt from extracted text

Tags: javascript, regex, eval, imacros

I have a website which gives the output as;

Host: 37.70.90.192 
Port: 21 
Username: sam 
Password: dean

Domain: example.net 
IP Address: 37.70.90.192 
Package: basic

This is a plain text with no tags for individual entries.
To extract the above I use

TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:CreatingAccountAccountInformation-------------------* EXTRACT=TXT

What I need to do is cut out everything except the ip address from this text. I don't know how to get the only that part of numbers. Hope you could help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must help:

```
SET ip EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/IP Address: (\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)/)[1];")
```

Comment: Thank you. I found a weird way too :)

SET VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.split('Package:').join('               ').split(' (')[0]") 
SET ID eval("\"{{VAR1}}\".match(/([IP ADDRESS])\w\d............./)[0]")

Comment: It’s really too weird…